# How can I change the order of suggested contacts in GMail app?

Tags: contacts, gmail

I regularly send email to a specific contact with the same first name as nearly a dozen other contacts, and he's always at the VERY BOTTOM of the list, which is annoying. Is there something I can do to get him to rise higher up the list so that he's the first suggestion instead of near the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

Gmail automatically sorts all the contacts based on your most frequent uses. But if you don't find that name at top, then you might consider saving a new contact.

To view a complete list of your most frequently mailed contacts, click Gmail at the top-left corner of your Gmail page, then choose Contacts. Next, click Most Contacted.

When you’re composing or replying to a message, hover over a contact’s name to see the email address associated with it, and double-click a contact’s name to edit it. If you have multiple email addresses linked to a contact, you’ll see your contact’s email address as well as name.

Comment: This seems to work on the web, but I'm looking for a change in the order in Android's GMail app.

Comment: If contact sharing is enabled, the contacts listed in your domain’s Google Apps Directory appear in the autocomplete. Refer https://support.google.com/a/answer/60218